# login failed for user ' token-identified principal ' - Azure synapse

Tags: azure-synapse

Im trying to create a table on Azure Synapse but I received the following error:

login failed for user ' token-identified principal '

I am contributor of Azure Subscription and on Synapse portal Im Apache admin, SQL admin and Workspace admin

What permissions are missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: f my answer is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, the Access control within Synapse Studio does not apply to dedicated SQL pools. Workspace admin can create a user manually through T-SQL or they can add you through SQL Active Directory Admin option when they navigate to workspace resource in Azure Portal.

**Reference:** [CREATE TABLE (Azure Synapse Analytics)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-azure-sql-data-warehouse?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7)

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.